# Next.js router.push does not change locale in URL

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm changing locale by binding the `onClick` to two `<div>` elements:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
// other codes

const router = useRouter()

const changeLocale = (locale) => {
    router.push({
        router: router.pathname,
        query: router.query
    }, router.asPath, { locale })
}

return <div>
    <div onClick={() => changeLocale('en')}>EN</div>
    <div onClick={() => changeLocale('ru')}>RU</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that it does not change the URL. When I go to `/en/about` and click this `RU` the URL does not become `/ru/about`.

Why `router.push` does not work as expected?

Comment: You have a typo, you probably meant `pathname: router.pathname` and not `router: router.pathname`. The URL object format does not have a `router` property. See https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#with-url-object.

Answer (score 1):

> Note
> `router.push({})` does not have the `router` property!

To handle routing, provide a list of locales and the default locale and Next.js will automatically handle the routing.

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    // These are all the locales you want to support in
    // your application
    locales: ['en', 'ru'],
    // This is the default locale you want to be used when visiting
    // a non-locale prefixed path e.g. `/hello`
    defaultLocale: 'en',
  },
}
```

Assuming you are using next 12, to add a prefix to the default locale, update your next config:

```js
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ['default', 'en', 'ru'],
    defaultLocale: 'default',
    localeDetection: false,
  },
  trailingSlash: true,
}
```

Next, to add a custom routing rules, create a new file `middleware.js` in your pages:

```js
// middleware.js

import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'

const PUBLIC_FILE = /\.(.*)$/

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  if (
    req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/_next') ||
    req.nextUrl.pathname.includes('/api/') ||
    PUBLIC_FILE.test(req.nextUrl.pathname)
  ) {
    return
  }

  if (req.nextUrl.locale === 'default') {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`/en${req.nextUrl.pathname}`, req.url))
  }
}
```

Please visit [nextjs docs to learn more about locale strategies](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#locale-strategies)

Comment: Thank you. But why my code does not work? Isn't `router.push` meant for programmatically change the route? Why should I use middleware for a simple, out-of-the-box routing scenario?

Comment: Hey @AliEXE `router.push` does not have the `router` property

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was that I had a submenu, and so the `router.push` with the default locale was being called a second time, causing the route to not change because there wasn't a locale change. You could add a check in your `changeLocale` method to return whether there is no locale provided.